# Find KeyAttribute of a class, defined using HasKey method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attributes, key

I am using Entity Framework Power Tools to generate database Model classes.
It uses HasKey() Method to define Key Attribute of a class.
Is there any way to find my key attribute of a class while using it in my application code?
Is there any way to check either a particular attribute is Key Attribute or not?

```
public class MyTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyTable>
{
   public MyTableMap()
   {
       // Primary Key
       this.HasKey(t => t.RecordID);
   }
 }
```

I am trying to find key attribute using following method, but its not working

```
if (propertyInfoObj.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute)))
```

Comment: "but its not working" - Error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue using the following method:

```
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
            ObjectSet<Entity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>();
            IEnumerable<string> keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                                        .KeyMembers
                                                        .Select(k => k.Name);

            string keyName = keyNames.FirstOrDefault();
```

Object property and/or value can be accessed by keyName using reflection.